# ClaimsIdentity AuthenticationType changed after deserialization using JwtSecurityTokenHandler

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

First off, a wider background.

I am working on a web application backed by a separate web API. The authentication in the web app should be ActiveDirectory based and it should be handled by the web API.

So, the `LogIn` action on `AccountController` on the web application only sends a post request to the `AuthenticationController` - and there I do AD Authentication using UserPrincipal and PrincipalContext.
The authentication works fine and I create some claims.

The problems start when I need to post back the result to the web app, so that I can do the 'SignIn' like below

```
if (result.Claims == null)
{
    this.Logger.Error($"Something went wrong when discovering identity of user [{model.UserName}]");
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Strings_Error.ErrorWhileDiscoveringUserIdentity);
}

IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, result.Claims);
```

I am using JwtSecurityTokenHandler to serialize the claims so that I can attach them to the response message from my Web Api controller.
The serialization happens as follows:

```
public static string GenerateToken(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
{
    SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ClaimsIndentitySerializer.SecurityKey));
    SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey,SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = identity,
        SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
        Issuer = IssuerKey,
        Audience = "http://www.mycompany.com",
    };

    SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    string tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return tokenString;
}
```

Then the generating claims from the string:

```
public static ClaimsIdentity ReadToken(this string token)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ClaimsIndentitySerializer.SecurityKey));

    TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidAudience = "http://www.mycompany.com",
        ValidIssuer = IssuerKey,
        IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
    };

    SecurityToken validatedToken = new JwtSecurityToken() as SecurityToken;
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

    return claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
}
```

I have created a unit test to check whether the claims match after being processed. And, much to my surprise, they are significantly different.

```
public void TestClaimsSerialization()
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TestName"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "TestNameIdentifier"));
    var token = identity.GenerateToken();
    var deserialized = token.ReadToken();
    Assert.Equal(identity.Name, deserialized.Name);
    Assert.Equal(identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value, deserialized.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    Assert.Equal(identity.AuthenticationType, deserialized.AuthenticationType); //the last assert fails
}
```

The error is
`Expected: ApplicationCookie Actual:   AuthenticationTypes.Federation`

Other Asserts are OK, so the values are actually preserved.

Any idea why?

Comment: 'The problems start when I need to post back the result to the web app,'. Do you have any problems with your code or is it just in `TestClaimsSerialization` that shows one not expected value?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg - well, the test method here shows the same as when the code is run - the claims that I get from `'token.ReadToken()` have different AuthenticationType (Federation vs ApplicationCookie), so it does not authenticate my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by changing

```
return claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

to

```
return new ClaimsIdentity(claimsPrincipal.Claims, "​​ApplicationCookie");
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same problem by add `AuthenticationType` parameter to `TokenValidationParameters`.

```cs
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RequireExpirationTime = true,
    RequireSignedTokens = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = issuer,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = audience,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie"
};
```